# AssertionError: The `request` argument must be an instance of `django.http.HttpRequest`, not `rest_framework.request.Request`

Tags: python, django, framework

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 488, in dispatch
    request = self.initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 392, in initialize_request
    parser_context=parser_context
  File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py", line 157, in **init**
    .format(request.**class**.**module**, request.**class**.**name**)
AssertionError: The `request` argument must be an instance of `django.http.HttpRequest`, not `rest_framework.request.Request`.

Comment: Django==2.2.6
djangorestframework==3.9.0

Comment: Can you please tell me how you fixed this error?